# Enable ambient sounds on inventory screen in the Enhanced Editions of the Infinity Engine games

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced, icewind-dale, baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

I'm currently playing Icewind Dale Enhanced Edition and find it very distracting that every time I enter e.g. the inventory screen I'm met with complete silence. It feels awful. All ambient sounds are muted and I've come to expect getting punched in the ears like this every time I want to manage items or spells, and it greatly breaks immersion.

Granted, sometimes, with long pauses, there's music playing that will continue to play on these screens, but often I'm met with only silence.

Is there a mod or something that can alleviate this? I imagine I'm not the only one since I think this behavior is the same for all Beamdog's EEs.

I did a search but nothing stood out, and I've already had details about the ending spoiled by the search result excerpts in another search, so I'm a bit wary...